# Python selenium, fake-useragent, не работает random

Tags: python, selenium, useragent

Ошибка:

> options.add_argument(f"user-agent={UserAgent.random}")
> AttributeError: type object 'FakeUserAgent' has no attribute 'random'

Код:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={UserAgent.random}")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="E:\Code\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

try:
    driver.get(url="https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent")
    time.sleep(4)
    # driver.refresh()
    # time.sleep(5)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Смотрел код на ютубе, повторяю все точь в точь, но почему то выдает ошибку.

Comment: `UserAgent().random`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если user agent берется из списка импортируемого файла:

> options.add_argument(f"user-agent={random.choice(UserAgent)}")